# rescue_from not working with ActionController::BadRequest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Using Rails 4, I can't get `rescue_from` to work with `ActionController::BadRequest`:

**application_controller.rb**

```
  rescue_from ActionController::BadRequest, with: :raise_bad_request

  def raise_bad_request
    render(nothing: true, status: 404)
  end
```

Comment: Do you have other rescue_from statements?  Order matters.

Comment: I do, but I'm not sure I understand how?  I have 3:  rescue_from ActionDispatch::RemoteIp::IpSpoofAttackError, with: :ip_spoof_error
  rescue_from ActionController::UnknownFormat, with: :raise_not_found
  rescue_from ActionController::BadRequest, with: :raise_not_found

Comment: Same issue here, couldn't solve it...

Answer (score 15):

Inside controller you can use `rescue_from` only for errors that raise inside your controller (in actions, views or filters).

It looks like `ActionController::BadRequest` raises before routing passes request to controller (somewhere in middleware stack).

You can process such errors if you write own middleware like this:

```
class HandleErrorsMiddleware

  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    @app.call(env)
  rescue ActionController::BadRequest
    ApplicationController.action(:raise_bad_request).call(env)
  end
end
```

`raise_bad_request` should be public method in `ApplicationController`

You should add this middleware in `config/application.rb`

```
config.middleware.insert_before 'ActionDispatch::ParamsParser', 'HandleErrorsMiddleware'
```

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't figure out why I was having trouble rescuing ActionController::UrlGenerationError until I found this article. Nice to know how things work, thanks.